# Is there documentation for the voip.ms API that shows parameters for functions

Tags: api

The link to Documentation and Examples on the voip.ms website shows a list of functions with no details of parameters and there are no examples.

Tech support at voip.ms said that's all there is I can't understand how how someone can build an application using the API without these details

Answer (score 0):

The list of function parameters can be found in the SOAP WSDL at https://voip.ms/api/v1/server.wsdl or in their example code at https://voip.ms/api/v1/API.zip